# Android mysterious background color difference (from API 17 to 16)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm pretty new to the android development environment. I've already learned a lot but something weird is happening for the API 16 which is not happening on API 17. I am not able to figure out what the problem is.

On API 16 there is a dark background added around the normal Webview website while on API 17 it is the correct white background.

Did anyone already face this issue? I did already try to change the styling XMLs without any positive result. On the page showing there is no background CSS applied so can not be CSS related.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should give the theme in the style value like Theme.AppCompat.Light or if it it is not working then you should change the container color to the white which is having the web view.